# Module parse failed: Unexpected token google-spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, google-sheets-api

I am new to webpack. I'm getting the following error. I don't really know how to go about resolving this issue. It occurs in the google-spreadsheet library https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet.

Would ignoring the folder that contain the google-spreadsheet when webpack bundles everything fix this issue?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-spreadsheet/lib/GoogleSpreadsheet.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (164:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       requests,
|       includeSpreadsheetInResponse: true,
|       ...responseRanges && {
|         responseIncludeGridData: true,
|         ...responseRanges !== '*' && { responseRanges },
 @ ./node_modules/google-spreadsheet/index.js 1:26-60
 @ ./src/client/internal-tools/autotranslation/utils/googleAPI.js
 @ ./src/client/internal-tools/autotranslation/index.js
 @ ./src/client/InternalTools.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./src/client/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-spreadsheet/lib/GoogleSpreadsheetWorksheet.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (41:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     return this._spreadsheet._makeSingleUpdateRequest(requestType, {
|       // sheetId: this.sheetId,
|       ...requestParams,
|     });
|   }
 @ ./node_modules/google-spreadsheet/index.js 2:35-78
 @ ./src/client/internal-tools/autotranslation/utils/googleAPI.js
 @ ./src/client/internal-tools/autotranslation/index.js
 @ ./src/client/InternalTools.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./src/client/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using that library instead of the official [Google Sheets API > Node](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sheets/classes/Sheets.html).

Comment: @JoseVasquez It was just easier and faster to implement fetching the sheet data. I could just use the official google sheet api, but it would take some time to figure the OAuth configuration

Comment: @JoseVasquez I switched to the official google sheet api, but i'm still getting module parse failed. this time with different module (i.e. ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js, ./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/http2.js, and ./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

I used webpack.IgnorePlugin(/googleapi/) to get it to work.